# separate multiple values from a key into their own key/value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary, data-processing

If we have the following list of dictionary:

> df=[{'answers': ['Yes', 'No'], 'question': 'status', 'type': 'string'}]

How can I split the above list into two dictionaries with only single value for answers key:

> df=[{'answers': ['Yes'], 'question': 'status', 'type': 'string'}, {'answers': ['No'], 'question': 'status', 'type': 'string'}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean you work with DataFrames (hence your variable name `df`). In that case pandas has already a function for this specific use case: `explode`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'answers': ['Yes', 'No'], 'question': 'status', 'type': 'string'}])
print(df.explode('answers'))
```

Output:

```
  answers question    type
0     Yes   status  string
0      No   status  string
```

Edit: you can easily get back to a dictionary form with `to_dict`:

```
df = df.explode('answers')
print(df.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Output:

```
[{'answers': 'Yes', 'question': 'status', 'type': 'string'}, {'answers': 'No', 'question': 'status', 'type': 'string'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  import copy 
    df=[{'answers': ['Yes', 'No'], 'question': 'status', 'type': 'string'}]
    df2=copy.deepcopy(df)
    content = df[0]
    for x,y in content.items():
      if (len(y) > 1) and isinstance(y,list):
        df[0][x]=y[0]
        df2[0][x]=y[1]
    # print(df)
    print(df2)
    print(df)
```

however this works only for 2 lists not more